Integrated Bluetooth doesn't work
Hi my integrated bluetooth dont work, im using my dongle for now.
I have MS-7E26 motherboard, can someone help me out how to enable it? Is this about the Kernel? I have 6.8.0-51-generic, thank you.
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop (GNOME).
0d:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:8125] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [1462:7e26]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
0e:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7922 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:0616]
    Subsystem: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7922 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:0616]
    Kernel driver in use: mt7921e
    Kernel modules: mt7921e
0f:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 600 Series Chipset USB 3.2 Controller [1022:43f7] (rev 01)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0db0:0076 Micro Star International MYSTIC LIGHT 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2357:0604 TP-Link TP-Link UB500 Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
[sudo] password for boris: 
[    0.250011] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[   68.629755] systemd[1]: Mounting snap-firmware\x2dupdater-127.mount - Mount unit for firmware-updater, revision 127...
[   68.630284] systemd[1]: Mounting snap-firmware\x2dupdater-147.mount - Mount unit for firmware-updater, revision 147...
[   68.932702] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   68.952441] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[   68.952444] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   68.952447] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   68.952450] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   68.952456] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   68.977385] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0a hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0a lmp_subver=8761
[   68.978387] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[   68.978390] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin
[   68.980480] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_config.bin
[   68.980598] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 6, total sz 30210
[   69.107740] mt7921e 0000:0e:00.0: WM Firmware Version: ____000000, Build Time: 20240219103337
[   69.129383] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0xdfc6d922
[   70.917180] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   70.917182] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   70.917185] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   70.917844] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[   71.015450] Bluetooth: hci0: Invalid link address type 1 for 14:3f:a6:19:17:f5
[   72.157111] [drm] Loading DMUB firmware via PSP: version=0x02020020
[   72.157450] [drm] Found VCN firmware Version ENC: 1.30 DEC: 3 VEP: 0 Revision: 4
[   72.157460] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
[   72.865696] [drm] Loading DMUB firmware via PSP: version=0x05000F00
[   72.866011] [drm] Found VCN firmware Version ENC: 1.30 DEC: 3 VEP: 0 Revision: 4
[   72.866017] amdgpu 0000:11:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
[   73.927312] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   73.927317] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   73.927321] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  508.562945] audit: type=1400 audit(1735729212.818:200): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.firmware-updater" name="/proc/6615/maps" pid=6615 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  508.794655] audit: type=1400 audit(1735729213.050:201): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firmware-updater.firmware-notifier" name="/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count" pid=6587 comm="firmware-notifi" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[11298.787741] audit: type=1400 audit(1735740003.038:264): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.firmware-updater" name="/proc/46120/maps" pid=46120 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[11298.978625] audit: type=1400 audit(1735740003.229:265): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firmware-updater.firmware-notifier" name="/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count" pid=46096 comm="firmware-notifi" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[22108.465800] audit: type=1400 audit(1735750812.718:355): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.firmware-updater" name="/proc/83598/maps" pid=83598 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[22108.500446] audit: type=1400 audit(1735750812.753:356): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firmware-updater.firmware-notifier" name="/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count" pid=83581 comm="firmware-notifi" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

